# How to define default style for InnerBlocks template for Gutenberg Block Editor (WordPress)

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am using gutenbergs' core block to make another block using InnerBlock. So, I want to change their default style like text align center.To start, I used officially supported way to create blocks [Create-Guten-Block](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/create-block).  My codes are as follows:

```js
import {
    InnerBlocks, useBlockProps
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import './editor.scss';

export default function Edit() {
    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <InnerBlocks
                template={ [
                    [ 'core/columns', {},
                        [
                            [ 'core/column', {}, [
                                    [ 'core/paragraph', { content: '$200' } ],
                                ]
                            ],
                            [ 'core/column', {}, [
                                    [ 'core/button', { placeholder : 'Buy Now' } ],
                                ]
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                ] }
                templateLock="all"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

WordPress uses **has-text-align-left** class to align a text in the block.
Is there any way to define default style inside the core/button's text-align to center inside the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `core/button` block [supports align](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/core-blocks/#button) and can be set in the block attribute `align` within the InnerBlocks template, eg:

```html
...
    ['core/button', { placeholder: 'Buy Now', align: 'center' }],
...
```

The resulting HTML then has the built-in style `aligncenter` applied and the button is now center aligned:

```html
<div class="wp-block-button aligncenter">
    <a class="wp-block-button__link">Buy Now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just one more help please. Could you please suggest more elaborated documents on the usage of inner blocks and their default styles or any example blocks that are build on core blocks of WordPress.

Comment: @johirHaqueDipok The [core/columns](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/columns) is built with InnerBlocks and a good place to see how they are used. With the InnerBlocks template, you can specify any attribute the block you are adding [supports](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/core-blocks/) also, if you want to add your own custom css class, you can use `['core/button', { placeholder: 'Buy Now', className: 'my-css-name' }]`.