# wp.blockEditor.RichText multiline prop is deprecated

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Getting this warning:

> wp.blockEditor.RichText multiline prop is deprecated since version 6.1
> and will be removed in version 6.3. Please use nested blocks
> (InnerBlocks) instead. https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/

I navigate to the link and the documentation offers no explanation how to properly code and format an unordered list without the **multiline** prop.

This is the snippet of my code in question:

```
el( RichText, {
    tagName: 'ul',
    multiline: 'li',
    placeholder: i18n.__(
        'Enter a list of price options…',
        'simplified-menu'
    ),
    value: attributes.price_list,
    onChange: function( value ) {
        props.setAttributes( { price_list: value } );
    },
    className: 'price_list',
} )
```

Answer (score 1):

WordPress Gutenberg contains a [List block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/core-blocks/#list) which creates both ordered and unordered lists. Depending on your needs, you could replace your custom RichText component with the core List block and extend it [using hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#blocks-registerblocktype) to add extra properties if needed.

Comment: This is just a portion of the block code. The block is robust and includes many elements, one of which is a price list. I have yet to find any documentation outlining how to include an existing block or its functionality in a custom block. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Existing blocks can be included in your custom block with [InnerBlocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/).  For your price list, you could styling it by adding custom classes or extend it [with block filters for the save function](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#blocks-getsaveelement). Also see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71248299/how-to-define-default-style-for-innerblocks-template-for-gutenberg-block-editor/) for ideas on InnerBlock templates